# PHPickerViewController, Double tap on image calls didFinishPicking twice

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

That's the issue, tapping fast on an image in the PHPickerViewController calls the didFinishPicking method in the delegate several times, in my case causing concurrency issues that I will solve

I stopped this behavior by setting the delegate to nil in didFinishPicking before dismissing the picker, but I don't see this being an "expected" behavior

Is there a way to disable it or need to live with it?

Comment: What is the configuration you init the viewController with? Did you take a look here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration. Maybe try to limit to one selection only?

Comment: It is one selection only. It is very difficult to simulate in a real device (very easy with a mouse on the simulator), but for some reason some users are able to do it in a production environment